# can I create container with string variable instead of it name? c++

Tags: c++

Are the any ways to create a container using a previosly initialized string variable in c++?
Sonething like that, but working:

```
std::string nameOfCont;
std::cin >> nameOfCont;
std::vector <int> nameOfCont;
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve here? Since the code is compiled beforehand the variable names don’t matter in any way. Are you looking for std::map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do exactly that. But you could crate a *mapping* between *strings* and *vectors* like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> vectors;

std::string nameOfCont;
std::cin >> nameOfCont;

vectors[nameOfCont].push_back(12); // use "named vector" here
// etc...
```

All your "named vectors" have to be of the same type.